# Asp.net Sql Insert rows using select case

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

Im designing a website that allows a user to update a database with information. The problem I am having is that I have created various controls that are hidden when the page loads, but the user can click to unhide to add additional info.

The issue I am coming up against is writing the sql statement to handle identifying what controls are used. I have a viewstate count to let me know which panels are visible or not.

```
ViewState("count") = CInt(ViewState("count")) + 1
    Label1.Text = ViewState("count").ToString()
```

And then the code behind to write the SQL query I have looks like this

```
    Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim myConn As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim sqlstring As String
    Dim dd As String
    Dim mm As String
    Dim yy As String


    dd = Left(TextBox1.Text, 2)
    mm = Mid(TextBox1.Text, 4, 2)
    yy = Right(TextBox1.Text, 4)


    myConn = New SqlConnection("xxx")

    myConn.Open()

    Select Case Label1.Text
        Case Is = "0"
            sqlstring = "INSERT INTO Transactions (Date, Account, Payee, Chq_Num, Reference, GST_Rate, Amount, Document_Number, Bank_Account) VALUES ('" & yy & "-" & mm & "-" & dd & "','" & DropDownList3.SelectedValue & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "'," & DropDownList2.SelectedValue & "," & TextBox6.Text & "," & TextBox27.Text & ",'" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & "')"
        Case Is = "1"
            sqlstring = "INSERT INTO Transactions (Date, Account, Payee, Chq_Num, Reference, GST_Rate, Amount, Document_Number, Bank_Account) VALUES ('" & yy & "-" & mm & "-" & dd & "','" & DropDownList3.SelectedValue & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "'," & DropDownList2.SelectedValue & "," & TextBox6.Text & "," & TextBox27.Text & ",'" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & "') VALUES ('" & yy & "-" & mm & "-" & dd & "','" & DropDownList4.SelectedValue & "','" & TextBox7.Text & "','" & TextBox9.Text & "','" & TextBox8.Text & "'," & DropDownList5.SelectedValue & "," & TextBox10.Text & "," & TextBox27.Text & ",'" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & "')"
    End Select


    cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlstring, myConn)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    myConn.Close()

    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, True)

End Sub
```

My problem lies in the select case as when case is 1 it is only inserting the first values and not the second set.  I have up to 6 "cases" to choose from, each time adding an additional set of values. Sql server is 2008

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What's the text of the error?

Comment: no error, only the first set of values gets inserted

Comment: Do a DEBUG.PRINT of the sqlstring before ExecuteNonQuery and try to run that in SSMS. I'm thinking it will show errors for statements 2 onwards.

Comment: Right so the issue is when i am clicking my post button to insert the transaction into my SQL database, the label text is still 0, yet clearly on my page it is showing 1 or 2 etc any ideas why it is not picking the true value up?

Comment: All sorted now, I passed the label.text to a hidden textbox and now it works, thanks Richard for your help

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but in the second statement the clause `VALUES` appears two two times.
That might be the source of your problem.

Comment: I have tried it without the second value and just a comma between the brackets, but no luck

Comment: Have you tried terminating your TSQL statement with ; (a semicolon) ?
Also have you got access to SQL Profiler, to see what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2008 onwards, you can use the multi-values insert clause that looks like this

```
INSERT [INTO] tbl [(...columns...)]
VALUES (....),(....),(....);
```

You have constructed your query like this

```
INSERT [INTO] tbl [(...columns...)]
VALUES (....)
VALUES (....)
VALUES (....)
```

I would also personally have constructed the string concatenation *not* using a SELECT-CASE block:

```
If Label1.Text >= "0" Then
        sqlstring = "('" & yy & "-" & mm & "-" & dd & "','" & DropDownList3.SelectedValue & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "'," & DropDownList2.SelectedValue & "," & TextBox6.Text & "," & TextBox27.Text & ",'" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & "')"
End If
If Label1.Text >= "1" Then
        sqlstring = sqlstring + "," + "('" & yy & "-" & mm & "-" & dd & "','" & DropDownList4.SelectedValue & "','" & TextBox7.Text & "','" & TextBox9.Text & "','" & TextBox8.Text & "'," & DropDownList5.SelectedValue & "," & TextBox10.Text & "," & TextBox27.Text & ",'" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & "')"
End If
' etc
```

If for whatever arcane reason the multi-values statement doesn't work, you can always rely on the tried and true multi-statement batch, i.e.

```
If Label1.Text >= "0" Then
    sqlstring = "INSERT ... VALUES (...);"
End If
If Label1.Text >= "1" Then
    sqlstring = sqlstring + "INSERT ... VALUES (...);"
End If
If Label1.Text >= "2" Then
    sqlstring = sqlstring + "INSERT ... VALUES (...);"
End If
' etc
```

Note the semicolon statement terminators within the batch.

Comment: I just tried the values (.....),(....) etc and it doesnt seem to work, i still just get the first values. I do like you if statement though, i will use that!

Comment: Hi Richard, I have tried doing INSERT... VALUES (....); INSERT.... VALUES(...); and still no luck, just the first set being inserted

Answer (score 0):

as above however you are going to end up with a horribly long string by the 6th case might want to re-engineer it to check >= each value if the previous strings are immutable

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not the select case but the viewstate not passing to the sql string correctly, I know possibly not the best solution but passed the label.text to a hidden textbox, which the sql string was able to read properly. Richard's suggestion to use a concatenated IF statement instead of Select Case was a great idea!

Thanks for all the help